# Can I delay selection of a file name?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

XP SP3

I have my folder options set up so that I do not need to double click on an item to open it. However, I find that items are selected  when I move over them swiftly. This is a problem when I want to save a file and inadvertently pass over another file name. It immediately gets selected.

Is there a way to delay this selection for, say, a second so that they are not selected so quickly?

Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Why would things be selected when you mouse over them?  Or are you using a trackpad?

Comment: I'm using a mouse. I guess I'm not clear enough. I have my folder options set so that when I hover over a file, an underline appears and I only need to single click to select the item. With this setting, the file is selected simply by hovering. However, I am finding that files are selected too quickly, so that if saving something for example, and I happen to pass over another file in that folder, the file name will change rather than staying with the original file name. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the Tweakui powertoy from Microsoft includes an option to change the mouse hover time, it's available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx)